# React Redux project architecture

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new for React -Redux.
For creating a project Is there any command available so that It's create default folder and file?

For Example:-
In Angular we can create project through Angular-Cli.

So, In React -Redux is there available something like that?

Comment: create-react-app is all, that you need ;) https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use create-react-app command this create form a structure like so:

[image]

[Source](https://daveceddia.com/react-project-structure/)

Comment: Yes, I already created project using this command.But it's gives only React architecture but I want to create app using Redux.

Answer (score 0):

As React is a only a view library the official [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) cli doesn't provide redux with it.

But there are alternatives like:
https://www.reactboilerplate.com

Also: you could get a boilerplate project integrated with backend of your choice. Like:

- https://github.com/geowarin/boot-react for Java Spring
- `dotnet new react-redux` for .Net Core

Answer (score 0):

Redux does not enforce any folder or file structure.

But there are some patterns and designs you can follow in React app.
Check the [docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#designing-component-hierarchy).